# How can Google, Facebook, etc find out which website you came from - when there is no referrer?

Tags: javascript, php, cookies, referrer

Let's say **Site A** is a traffic generating website. **User A** clicks on a banner on **Site A** and gets redirected to **Site B** (for example a landing page). From **Site B** there is a link to **Site C** (which is for example Facebook, Google, or any other big company).

**Question:**
How can **Site C** determine which sources did **User A** come from? Becuase I have seen a lot of **Site C** websites that knew which was **Site A**.

As far as I know, browsers cannot pass **Site A** referrer url to **Site C**. How do they do it anyway? Are they using any kind of PHP or Javascript code for that?

Comment: first you should realize that all of those sites probably have _Google_ Analytics or AdSense, _Facebook_ share widgets, etc. which they can use to track you everywhere.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it’s not a programming problem.

Comment: Are you going to select an answer?

Answer (score 2):

The way they know where you have been is because they drop cookies with unique IDs on your computer so they can track you.

For example if a website uses any Facebook widgets, Facebook is already tracking you and knows what ads to target you with based on the sites you have visited once you go back to Facebook.com, or if Google Analytics is on the website (which it probably will be) this is tracking everything you go on from one site to the next and doing the same with serving relevant ads.